# Why is this polynomial non-negative?

Tags: inequality, polynomials

Show that this polynomial is non-negative:
$$f(x,y)=x^2(x^2-1)^2+y^2(y^2-1)^2-(x^2-1)(y^2-1)(x^2+y^2-1)\ge 0,\forall x,y\in R$$

Comment: what have you done?

Comment: sorry,the last don't have square,and I have add edit

Comment: Try moving last term to right side and then divide.